# why does this code return a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'?

Tags: python-3.x

```
lwrnmbr = 0.0
hghrnmbr = 100.0
a = 1
```

### this loop seems to work fine until you actually enter "h" or "l"

```
while (a == 1):
guess = (lwrnmbr + hghrnmbr) / 2
guessword = str (guess)
answr = (input("are you thinking of "+ guessword + "? type 'h' if that's too high, type 'l' if it's too low, and type 'r' if it's right"))
if(answr == "h"): 
    hghrnmbr = answr
elif(answr == "l"):
    lwrnmbr = answr
elif(answr == "r"):
    print("thanks for playing")
    break
```

Comment: ...because once you enter h or l that thing you just explicitly checked was equal to another string gets assigned to what was formerly a number?

Comment: You want `hghrnmber` to be equal to `int(guessword)` in the if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were incorrectly reassigning hghrnmbr/lwrnmbr to be equal to the input you received, when I expect you wanted to set it to the guess you had made. Also make sure to cast `guessword` to an int before doing numeric operations on it.

```
while (a == 1):
guess = (lwrnmbr + hghrnmbr) / 2
guessword = str (guess)
answr = (input("are you thinking of "+ guessword + "? type 'h' if that's too high, type 'l' if it's too low, and type 'r' if it's right"))
if(answr == "h"): 
    hghrnmbr = int(guessword)
elif(answr == "l"):
    lwrnmbr = int(guessword)
elif(answr == "r"):
    print("thanks for playing")
    break
```